# Android - no app found to open link within Edittext

Tags: android, hyperlink, android-edittext

If I click on the HYPERLINK, I get a dialog with the message that no app was found to handle this link, but I know that my android device has some applications to handle this file, becuase I open this file already by click the file itself. Here the code snippet:

```
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                    final String DATA = event.getClipData().getItemAt(0).getText().toString();
                    final String RECORDS_DIR = ((ScribeApplication ) getApplication()).RECORDS_DIRECTORY_ABSOLUTE_PATH;
                    final Spanned HYPERLINK = Html.fromHtml("<a href=\"" + RECORDS_DIR + DATA + "\">" + RECORDS_DIR + DATA + "</a>");
                    editor.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
                    if (editor.length() > 0)
                    {
                        editor.append("\n");
                        editor.append(HYPERLINK);
                    }
                    else
                        editor.append(HYPERLINK);
                    return true;
```

- DATA is the file name e.g. record1.3pg
- RECORDS_DIR is the absolute path to the directory with the recording files.
- HYPERLINK is the absolute path of a record file.
- editor is an instance of Eidttext

As mentioned above, if I navigate to the records directory and click the record file itself I get an app chooser and can select an app to handle this record file. So what I did wrong that I dont get an app chooser by clicking the hyperlink within the edittext but rather an dialog with the failure that no app was found?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: "RECORDS_DIR is the absolute path to the directory with the recording files" -- if by that you mean that it is a path beginning with `/`, that is unlikely to work. There is no base URL, so you need to use an absolute URL, which means you need a scheme, such as `file://`.

Comment: @CommonsWare I have understood you well, thank you. But the problem is still there. Here are the changes what I did after your response:          `final String ABSOLUTE_URL = "file://" + RECORDS_DIR + '/' + DATA;
final Spanned HYPERLINK = Html.fromHtml("<a href=\"" + ABSOLUTE_URL + "\">" + ABSOLUTE_URL +  "</a>");`

Comment: "I navigate to the records directory and click the record file itself I get an app chooser and can select an app to handle this record file" -- there is no means to do this in standard Android. I presume that you are using some sort of file manager app that shipped with your device or that you installed. In that case, it may use `MimeTypeMap` to associate a MIME type with the `ACTION_VIEW` `Intent` that it uses. I don't know what a `.3pg` file is (`.3gp` is a media file; perhaps you have a typo), but the apps are probably working off the MIME type, not the file extension.

Comment: You may wind up having to use your own `ClickableSpan` subclass, mimicking [the `URLSpan` that is used by default for hyperlinks](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/text/style/URLSpan.java), that can add a MIME type to the `Intent`.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank you so much for understanding the problem and your hints to solve it. How can I thank you in stackoverflow style? For the sake of completeness  I will post the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution for the issue described by CommonsWare:

```
public class ClickableIntentURLSpan extends URLSpan
{
    private Context context;
    private Intent intent;

    public ClickableIntentURLSpan(final Context CONTEXT, final String URL, final Intent INTENT)
    {
            super(URL);
            final boolean INPUT_OK = (CONTEXT != null) && (INTENT != null);
            if (INPUT_OK)
            {
                context = CONTEXT;
                intent = INTENT;
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            }
            else
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal refer to null.");
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(final View VIEW)
    {
            context.startActivity(intent);
    }
}



                case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                    final String DATA = event.getClipData().getItemAt(0).getText().toString();
                    final String RECORDS_DIR = ((ScribeApplication ) getApplication()).RECORDS_DIRECTORY_ABSOLUTE_PATH;
                    final String ABSOLUTE_URL = "file://" + RECORDS_DIR + '/' + DATA;
                    final Intent PLAY_RECORD_INTENT = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    final File RECORD_FILE = new File(RECORDS_DIR, DATA);
                    PLAY_RECORD_INTENT.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(RECORD_FILE), "audio/*");
                    final ClickableIntentURLSpan INTENT_URL = new ClickableIntentURLSpan(getApplicationContext(), ABSOLUTE_URL, PLAY_RECORD_INTENT);
                    final SpannableString HYPERLINK = new SpannableString(DATA);
                    HYPERLINK.setSpan(INTENT_URL, 0, DATA.length(), 0);
                    editor.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
                    if (editor.length() > 0)
                    {
                        editor.append("\n");
                        editor.append(HYPERLINK);
                    }
                    else
                        editor.append(HYPERLINK);
                    return true;
```